# NSPredicate results to NSArray

Tags: ios, nsarray, uitableview, nspredicate

I want to put the results of the predicate into an array and then put it in a table view  but I'm still new with this.

```
- (IBAction)search:(id)sender
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];

    NSEntityDescription *entidesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [request setEntity:entidesc];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"nombre like %@ and apellido like %@",self.nombretext.text, self.apellidotext.text];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *matchingdata = [context executeFetchRequest:request error: &error];

    if(matchingdata.count == 0) {
        self.display.text = @"Persona no encontrada";
    } else {
        NSString *nombre;
        NSString *apellido;
        int count =0;

        for(NSManagedObject *obj in matchingdata)
        {
            count++;
            nombre =   [obj valueForKey:@"nombre"];
            apellido = [obj valueForKey:@"apellido"];
        }

        if(count == 1)
        {
            self.display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Nombre: %@,  Apellido: %@", nombre, apellido];
        } else {
            self.display.text = @"Mas de una persona con ese nombre o apellido, intente otra vez";}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what's wrong with what you have? Where is your table view code?

Comment: i was showing only this content in labels and only one line, I want to present the the entire filtered array in a tableview but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Have you read any table view tutorials? You really need to try something and then ask about issues you have.